# Compile ffmpeg with hwaccel

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-compilation, configure

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg with hwaccel support, but no matter the options I pass to the `configure` script, the enable hwaccels list always comes empty.

Running `./configure --help` says that, to enable a hwaccel, I should pass `--enable-hwaccel=NAME`, where `NAME` comes from the list of hwaccels supported.

I tried doing all of these (appending the option at the end of my `./configure` command):

```
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg1_vdpau
--enable-hwaccel mpeg1_vdpau
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg1
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg1*
```

But none of these helped. Can someone give me a light?

Edit: I added --enable-vdpau before --enable-hwaccel, and now it gives me this error:
`ERROR: vdpau requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: vdpau_vdpau_h vdpau_vdpau_x11_h`

I installed `libvdpau-dev`, but the error persists.

Edit2: I am cross-compiling `ffmpeg` for an ARM target (an AM3352, which as a SGX530 graphics accelerator) , does this have any influence on the hwaccel options?

Comment: (guessing ffmpeg works like a normal configure) Check your config.out or config.log to see where it is running the tests for those. Probably you're missing a some headers (e.g., from a -dev/-devel package)

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that I am cross-compiling? There is no indication of any error, but from the `config.log` file it seems that the option is not being selected, regardless of what I pass to the script.

Comment: Yeah... you'll need to make sure those headers are available for your cross-compiler, not your host system's compiler (and similarly, that the libs to link against for your cross-linker, not the host system's).

Comment: Also: you should consider if this would better fit on [so] than here. If you want it moved, flag your question, select "in need of moderator intervention", and ask for it to be moved to [so].

Comment: I wouldn't really consider building someone else's app to be a programming question

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with similar problem in configuring LibAV

```
./configure --target-os=mingw32 --arch=x86  --enable-shared --enable-static \
--enable-dxva2 --disable-encoders --enable-hwaccel=dxva2 --extra-cflags=-O3 \
--enable-pthreads
```

hw-accelerator of dxva2 was disabled since dxva2api.h was absent.

I suggest to specify where is located dxva2api.h and add its location to $path or copy it to a relevant directory.